# using similar method like .isin but with row number returned

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to get the row number of matching condition similar like .isin, part of dataframe are shown like this

df1

```
0    452525
1    110101
2    393910
```

df2

```
0     100000
1     110000
2     110100
3     110101
4     110102
5     110105
6     110106
7     110107
8     110108
9     110109
10    110111
11    110112
12    110113
13    110114
14    110115
```

when I use

```
t1.isin(t2)
```

I got

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
```

My desired output is

```
0    NaN
1    3
2    NaN
```

Is there a method to do this? But I want to avoid using pd.merge() since both dataframe is big, if merging them would take long time to execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary with swap values and index of `t2`:

```
#if t1, t2 are Series
out = t1.map(dict(zip(t2, t2.index)))

#if t1, t2 are Dataframes
out = t1['col'].map(dict(zip(t2['col'], t2.index)))
print (out)
0    NaN
1    3.0
2    NaN
Name: col, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `t1` and `t2` Series, I would use a `merge`:

```
t1.to_frame().merge(t2.reset_index(), how='left')['index']
```

output:

```
0    NaN
1    3.0
2    NaN
Name: index, dtype: float64
```

From the dataframes `df1` and `df2` and using "col" as column name:

```
df1.merge(df2.reset_index(), on='col', how='left')['index']
```

Comment: I said avoid merge in my question because these are sample data of a big dataframe, but thanks anyway

Comment: @AlexWithYou have you actually tested the timing? It's often better to ensure timings

Comment: and I got an error output MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False. Not the same as yours

Comment: @AlexWithYou you hadn't specified the column names. Use `left_on"col_name_left", right_on="col_name_right"`

Comment: I checked, it is slower. I took it into whole data. Yours take an average of 1.5 sec to excute, while jez method map dict takes 1.2 secs. That's why I typically choose to avoid "merge". But still appreciate your help

Comment: @AlexWithYou great that you checked ;)